# Building a database with Rails + Postgresql + Heroku

Tags: ruby, database, csv, heroku, postgresql-9.2

I'm building a web app where the user's need to choose from a database of exercises. They should be able to see the exercise name, description, and skill level. What is the best practice for building a database table for this purpose?

I'm thinking I could write each exercise and its attributes in a CSV file, then write a ruby script that would parse it and create an exercise object in the database table for each exercise that it parses. However, I have never done this before and would appreciate feedback.

And how would I migrate this database table from development to production on Heroku?

Thanks so much for any info.

Comment: if you are doing files yaml would be a better choice than csv. Though is you are putting them straight in the db, why do you need a file at all, have a look at rake db seed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an array of hashes and iterating over the array in seeds.rb:

```
[
    { 
        :name         => "",
        :description  => "",
        :skill_level  => ""
    },
# Input more hashes below

].each do |exercise|
  ExerciseDb.create(
    name: exercise[:name]
    description: exercise[:description]
    skill_level: exercise[:skill_level]
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an Exercise model with name, description, skill level, and something to store the actual exercise. It is up to you to figure out whether you want to read it in with csv or yaml - I agree that yaml would be easier. Also how to store the user's responses - hstore, json, serialized yaml...